# Laravel 4: Recursive table one to many

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a category system where categories can be descendants of other categories. I plan on having a category table and a second table managing the one-to-many relationships. I don't know how to refer back to a table in Laravel. Is it as simple as declaring a function with the same name as the class like I would if it was a different table? This is my current thought. If someone knows better, please let me know.

I'm used to coding things by hand in this case. I'm trying to use existing code for once.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to set relationship methods on the "Category" model that you're using.  For example, if you have a table called 'categories' with the fields 'parent_id' to keep track of the primary key (probably 'id' or 'category_id') of the parent category.

With that, you don't need a second table to handle any relationship information, just a single table with parents.

An example can be found [here](http://paste.laravel.com/2op)—I've pasted the relevant snippet below.

```
public function children() {
    return $this->has_many('Category', 'parent_id'); 
}
public function parent(){
    if($this->parent_id !== null && $this->parent_id > 0){
        return $this->belongs_to('Category','parent_id');
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That snippet can be originally referenced [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1675).